# Apacha Cordova | Ionic Framework. Не отображается символы кириллицы

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, mobile-development, ionic

При запуске приложения, под любую из платформ, не отображаются русские символы. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ! Нужно было сохранить проект через "Дополнительные параметры сохранения" и выбрать "utf-8" вместо "киррилица Windows"